# Why didn't Rukia's power transfer to Kaien dono when she pierce his heart?

Tags: bleach

In the beginning of series, it is said that Shinigami can transfer his/her power by stabbing a person's heart, just like Ichigo's case both as a human and as a semi-hollow (fullbring), and in the movie, where Ichigo seperate Rukia from a hollow and a soul (non-canon). However, this does not happen when Rukia did it to Kaien dono. **How could this happen?**

Comment: There probably has to be the intent to transfer powers for it to occur, otherwise you might transfer your powers mid-battle.

Comment: Thats probably why rukia likes to transfer power now.. she transferred twice in canon lol